# Switch Eclipse split window

Tags: windows, eclipse

So I have a a java project open. I have a split window setup going on where I can edit files on the left panel and view some other files on the right panel. The left panel has about 7 files open that I jump back and forth in. The right panel has about 9 files which is correlated to specific files on the left panel. I found out I have to start editing the files on the right. Is there anyway I can switch the panels so the 9 files on the right goes to the left panel and vise versa?

The easy way to do it is to close all the windows and reopen them on the specific panels I want. I don't want to close everything and open everything since the file structure are all over the place.

I'm just trying to be lazy since I don't want to crane my neck and lean over half a feet and edit on the right panel. I thought it would be a cool feature if it was implemented on eclipse.